# Confused over "Request to undelete" an answer

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, undelete

Straightforward situation but the help pages don't explain this aspect well, which surprises me. Can someone clarify for me, and perhaps update the Q&A/FAQ pages to help others who might also get confused?

I wrote an answer to ([this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/cheap-wifi-router-with-built-in-4g-modem-and-openvpn-support)). It was deleted by another user. My request here isn't about the merits of the deletion, it's about my understanding of the situation. The Q&A don't really explain this very well, and I'm confused.

The [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) *(section: "How can I undelete one of my posts?")* suggests asking on Meta if deletion was by "Trusted users". Following the link shows the user has 1869 rep compared to 20k needed for "trusted user", not immediately obvious but I found that info. So the answer wasn't deleted by a "Trusted user" or a moderator, perhaps it was deleted by the system...  but the Q&A doesn't actually seem to explain how such a deletion happens, or what to do about it. It isn't clear which type of deletion happened, if different methods have different follow-ups.

It looks like one way to appeal it is to ask via a post on "Meta", but it isn't clear which "Meta" that would be, there are many with that name - is it the Meta for that SE or the general Meta? I also have an "Undelete" button and a "Flag" for moderator attention link, but I'm not clear if it's appropriate to use those or if I should ask on whichever Meta site is meant.  If I use them how I clarify for other reviewers why I think it's appropriate, or indeed how I comment on such a delete/undelete action for others?

I figure that if I'm confused by these things, I imagine others will be, so could someone, as well as helping me understand these points, also improve the Q&A page to clarify for others as well?

I emphasise that I'm not asking "why was it deleted" or asking for undeletion here, I'm asking for help in understanding the confusing aspects of the delete/undelete system which aren't well explained when I went to read about it.

Comment: There is a moderator on that site with 1869 rep, so I'd say that was the one deleting your answer, you somehow missed the diamond on their profile. Each site got its own meta, in case of the question you linked to, the proper meta site to ask why your answer was deleted is [this one](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible.to look through the points mentioned in my OP and update the general deleted questions Q&A post I've linked, to clarify those points? There's no real benefit to clarifying the rest here when putting it there will be more visible and help others.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: The things that I mentioned, which have confused me (beyond those in your reply) - can you edit the Q&A page to make the answers clear, so they are there for anyone else with the same question in future.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted that answer; [I'm a moderator on Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/8/artofcode) (that's what the diamond signifies).

Moderators are automatically granted all privileges, including the ability to unilaterally delete any post, without needing to have the reputation that regular users need to get it.

Additionally, the 20k limit only applies to graduated sites; Hardware Recommendations is in public beta, so the rep required for the "trusted user" privilege is just 4k.

Comment: Thanks - again to emphasise that my post here is because these basics (to experienced users) which I mentioned in the OP aren't obvious to me, despite using SE quite a lot, so they may not be to others (diamond==mod, whodathought? Never knew that. Worth a mention in Q&A). Is the undelete link I get, "available but shouldnt be used here"? I assume from your reply that HWSE meta is the appropriate route be to discuss or request undelete? (I don't want to clutter up this thread about the deletion Q&A, by discussing the actual question here)

Comment: @Stilez HR meta is the right place for that, yes. The undelete link you have is there, but it won't work because the post was deleted by a diamond mod, which prevents regular users from undeleting it.